# Querying Hstore and nil with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have a model `Profile` with a hstore column called `meta_data`

This is an example of it:

```
{"bio" => "", username => nil, "location" => "earth, "gender" => "male}
```

When I query:

```
Profile.where("meta_data @> hstore('gender', 'male')")
```

Works great!

But now I need to query for username being `nil` and that's when it all fails cause it's technically not a string?

```
Profile.where("meta_data @> hstore('username', 'nil')")
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 


Profile.where("meta_data @> hstore('username', nil)")
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "nil" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ROM "profiles"  WHERE (meta_data @> hstore('username', nil))
                                                                  ^
: SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE (meta_data @> hstore('username', nil))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "nil" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ROM "profiles"  WHERE (meta_data @> hstore('username', nil))
                                                                  ^
: SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE (meta_data @> hstore('username', nil))
```

Would like to query to find those that are not nil.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Answered my own question, have to use null instead of nil, ActiveModel just outputs it as nil but it's null in the database

```
Profile.where("meta_data @> hstore('username', null)")
```

Comment: can you share your model here.

Comment: @osleonard my model is huge!